Prevent Windows from creating token-username credentials for TFS in Credential Manager
I work with on-premise TFS instances as admin and got an issue from several users.
These users sporadically get a fake tfs username/password credential in Windows's Credential Manager for the TFS server address. This appears in the Windows Credentials and also in the Generic Credentials (here with https prefix) part.
When this credential appears automatically, the access fails in Visual Studio, in Browser and in all Git applications. If we remove them, the access works again.
The username seems like a token and starts with @@.
Do you have any experience regarding this and ideas how to avoid its creation?
The workaround is the removal, but we should prevent the creation. Maybe this is a Windows Group policy thing.
